# How do I remove meta tags from a string using C++?

Tags: c++, regex, string

Need help figuring out how to extract text from context (Honda from str), need something analogous to Perl regex

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string str;
    str = "<make>Honda</make>";
    //Code to extract Honda from above string
    cout<<str<<endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If that string is XML, what you need is an XML parser, not a regex engine. Please search, there are a bunch of options available.

Comment: What do you mean by "something analogous to"? Analogous in what way? In the sense that it parses data? That's pretty vague...

Comment: You definitely do **not** want to use reg expressions to parse an HTML document. If its a one line string you may get away with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> need something analogous to Perl regex

Is this a trick question? :) That "something" is PCRE: "Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions".

What you *really* need is `libxml2`, and the XPath query `//meta/text()`.

Comment: +1: Though this question would be better with a bit of formatting. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks! That has done it, no trick question. Just wanted to remove text from the string using rules, just like regex in Perl. I figured it out in MSXML6.

Answer (score -1):

In C# (I don't know programming in C#), I know there is Regex but in C++ it may be included in external libraries

Comment: why you keep downboting me ? I'd like to annuonce I have something to announce": why ?

Comment: Who are you talking to? "Announce"? What are you talking about?

Comment: Ask yourself in what way this answer answers the question. C# is not relevant at all, and you didn't really say anything about C++.

Comment: FYI, Boost provides a regex library, and it was incorporated into C++0x. But regex is not the right tool for this job.